# Can I reuse my c++ library in android application using JNI layer?

Tags: java, android

If the S/W layer hierarchy as followings,

```
android app (java)
|
JNI (to use c++ library)
|
my c++ library (cross compile according to android toolchain)
```

My c++ library is development based on Ubuntu environment.

In thie case, can I reuse my c++ library in android application using JNI layer?

or

Do I need to do more to reuse my c++ library?

p.s) If you know good example like my case, could you let me know the link of example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  You will need to build the header files using the Java jni tool from your Java interfacing code, and then provide implementation code to bridge between c++ and jni.

Comment: Thanks. Could you recommend the example code or good guide page?